# Python OBD on android

Tags: android, python, obd-ii

I have installed python obd on an android. However, when I scanned for bluetooth, it shows *no devices available*. Can anyone help me in implementing python obd running on an android device? 
Thank you

Comment: can you point to python obd? and it's very much depend on hardware you connecting. Which hardware you using?

Comment: i want to connect to an elm327 bluetooth adapter.. I can connect to it on my windows laptop using python obd. But not on android.